# Tag concern: [multiway-tree]

Tags: discussion, tags

Someone is going around tagging a lot of questions that are only tangentially related to multiway trees with the [multiway-tree] tag. I'm concerned that it's being used incorrectly. Some examples:

- [Dualities between data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164030/dualities-between-data-structures)
- [Good references for algorirtm efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757889/good-references-for-algorithm-efficiency) (no clue why this was tagged)
- [Practical applications of data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538138/practical-applications-of-data-structures) (tries are mentioned tangentially in the question but otherwise unrelated)
- [Confused about dealing with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794464/c-confused-in-dealing-with-multiple-classes) (question talks about AVL trees, which are binary trees and not multiway trees.)

I'm rolling back some of these changes, but it's annoying to do this by hand.

Are there inappropriate retags? Can anything be done to address this?

Comment: Retagging closed questions, hmmm... I can't find my pitchfork right now, did you try leaving a comment to the editor?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi- After the ninth or so I did. Is someone trying to game the system to get a tagging badge or archaeologist badge?

Comment: [The retagger created the tag](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18087288/revisions), hit 2k not too long ago, and [the last 20 edits of his were simply retags](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1449636/joel?tab=activity&sort=revisions), so yeah, I'm suspicious.

Comment: @Dukeling- Ooof, and that's not even the right definition of a multiway tree. >_< Fixing...

Comment: @templatetypedef It's preferable to **rollback**, not simply retag it again (even if you rollback **then** edit it to make other fixes) - the system can pick up on rollbacks, not sure if it actually does anything about them though (I know it takes rollbacks into account for edit wars on a post).

Comment: Flagged one of these, let's see what comes out of it.

Comment: "that's not even the right definition of a multiway tree" - yeah, that's the problem with our current review system, and ironically the opposite of the problem with the tag synonyms system.

Comment: Funny so I thought I should share: the editor in question also likes to approve minor edits, and apparently shares its activity between that and retagging. Looks like a review drone with the retag update. Damn, those minerals *do* work.

Comment: I apologize, I am the user in question.  I am not trying to "game the system" or anything.  I just thought a multiway-tree tag would be beneficial so I tried to put it out there and add it to relevant questions. That's what caused all the minor edits. Sorry if this was an inappropriate use of tagging

Comment: @Joel, but why on closed questions, then? And why did you think those questions were worth a `[multiway-tree]` tag in the first place?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I had just done a question search of "multiway tree" and added the tag to several of the questions that came in the results. Of course, I see now that several of the results came up simply because the keywords were in an answer, not the question.  I am sorry, I should have paid closer attention.